# Compiler says "Illegal Instruction" to a piece of simple code

Tags: c

It's just a simple code for checking if a number is prime or not, I don't know if it is the compiler or the code which is the problem here.
A bit of help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
    int n,i,c=0;
    printf ("\n Enter a Number:");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
         if (n%i==0)
         {
             c++;
         }
     }
     if (c==2)
     {
         printf ("\n Prime Number");
     }
     else
     {
         printf ("\n Not a Prime Number");
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: clang? and on which line?

Comment: The compiler doesn't specify, sadly

Comment: What compiler doesn't at the very least report what line an error is on?

Comment: It's an independent compiler for Android, It just doesn't ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Is it capable of compiling C code? `#include "stdio.h"` looks strange did you just copy paste the header in or why are you using `""` instead of `<>`? Or does the preprocessor demands that?

Comment: " " works just fine and I typed the code myself

Comment: Maybe it would be useful to tell which compiler you are using since this seems to be a compiler problem.

Comment: It was called "C4Droid" the last time I checked, so..

Comment: comment 1 line and recompile; if the same error persists assume it's because it's on a different line, so repeat until you find the 'guilty' line. If the same error exists on more than 1 line, this will not find the error :(

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that in a bit

Comment: Google for "C4Droid illegal instruction", you will get several hits

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
 #include "stdio.h"
```

You are indicating that the compiler should look for the stdio.h in a specific location known to the compiler (usually the source file directory but it can vary depending on the compiler), the illegal instruction migth be due to either a faulty (badly implemented library) or simply a non existent stdio.h

This is why compilers usually have their standard libraries on their own known location and it's referred to by using

```
 #include <stdio.h>
```

Since the compiler you're using does not provide details, there's no way to know where is the error originating

Edit: You could test your code in incremental steps avoiding the use of printf and scanf, this can be accomplished by using test variables and return values. As I've said there's no way to know exactly where the faulty instruction is being generated due to a non-standard stdio.h implementation but my guess is the scanf return signature which means an uncompilable for loop. Test your code

Comment: I've done plenty of coding on the compiler but never once saw this error, I even tried using "<>" but to no avail.

Comment: While using ` #include "stdio.h"` instead of ` #include <stdio.h>` is unusual, it is most likely not the problem here.

Comment: The problem is not related to c but to a specific compiler and its libraries implementation. It needed to be pointed out.

Comment: I really have no idea on what the problem is here